# Jquery .first pseudo selector with specific id

Tags: jquery, filter, pseudo-element

If i use

```
        $("#list1 li:first").css("border","1px solid green");
```

It does not work. Whereas If i change to

```
        $("ul:first li:first").css("border","1px solid green");
```

It works. Looks like if i use the pseudo selectors i will have to use only pseudo selector not mixing with the specific id. Why? Any thoughts?

```
<body>
        <h1>JQuery Various Selection/Filtering</h1>
        <ul id="#list1">
            <li class="a">List 0</li>
            <li class="b">List 1</li>
            <li class="a">List 2</li>
            <li class="b">List 3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="#list2">
            <li class="a">List 0</li>
            <li class="b">List 1</li>
            <li class="a">List 2</li>
            <li class="b">List 3</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="a">Paragraph 0</p>
        <p class="b">Paragraph 1</p>
        <p class="a">Paragraph 2</p>
        <p class="b">Paragraph 3</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Because your id is `"#list1"` (with a hash sign), not plain `"list1"`. Therefore, to match it you have to use `$("#\\#list1")`, not `$("#list1")` (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea8Ltqqk/)). I would advise you remove these hash signs from your ids.

Comment: Thanks Frédéric Hamidi. My silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # in your id. http://jsfiddle.net/vd56mfgz/

```
    <ul id="list1">
        <li class="a">List 0</li>
        <li class="b">List 1</li>
        <li class="a">List 2</li>
        <li class="b">List 3</li>
    </ul>
```